# Kafka Docker setup

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

Can someone point out how to setup kafka with docker? I have tried every tutorial I could find and I got the same error:

> Can't resolve YYYYYYY:PORT adress where YYYYYYY is the container id

I tried using kafka listeners, kafka advertised host name, kafka port and kafka advertised listeners enviroment variables but nothing worked. I mapped all ports `9092:9092` and `2181:2181`.

If someone has a working Dockerfile with kafka I would apreaciate it.

Comment: might help https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/tree/5.0.0-post/examples

Comment: When you say you're "tried tutorials", it would be great if you could link to them, so we can find out if you've done something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> YYYYYYY:PORT adress where YYYYYYY is the container id

Without seeing *your Dockerfile* and the commands you've tried, sounds to me like you are not using `localhost` outside of the container to access the Docker image, or using the Docker *image name*, **not** the container ID.

If a tutorial is showing it working, then I wouldn't think seeing another Dockerfile would help... TBH, just seems like a misconception that the container ID is relevant; or even if you used the container name externally of the container, it's a network error because it is not available to your DNS servers

That all being said, [Confluent Quick Start (Docker)](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html) gives a good overview of not just Kafka, but also Zookeeper and other Kafka related components

Answer (score 2):

See https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.0.0-post/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml for an example of a working Docker Compose.

Also, you need to get your networking configuration right, as Kafka works across hosts and needs to be able to access them all. [This post](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) explains it in detail.